# ASP.NET Code behind not recognising control ID, error 'The name does not exist in current context'

Tags: asp.net

I'm testing out some code that calculates the days by subtracting 2 dates and posting back the number of days in between.

Here is the first test:

CalculateDaysTest1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalculateDaysTest1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Templates.CalculateDaysTest1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Calculate Dates Test 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="formitem">
            <asp:Label ID="startDateLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="Start Date:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="DatePicker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="calculateDays"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="formitem">
            <asp:Label ID="endDateLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="End Date:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID ="txtEndDate"  CssClass="DatePicker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="calculateDays"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="formitem">
            <asp:Label ID="totalDaysLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="Number of Days:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="totalDays" CssClass="idlabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.DatePicker').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:2100'
            });
        })
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CalculateDaysTest1.cs

```
using System;

namespace PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Templates
{
public partial class CalculateDaysTest1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void calculateDays(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string startdate = txtStartDate.Text;
        string enddate = txtEndDate.Text;
        if (startdate != "" && enddate != "")
        {
            DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
            DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);
            totalDays.Text = t2.Subtract(t1).Days.ToString();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything here is working perfectly and it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. You can select the start and end date and it posts back the calculated days.

Now for the second test I'm using it in the context of a Form View Control using model binding.

Here is Test 2:

CalculateDaysTest2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalculateDaysTest2.aspx.cs" Inherits="PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Templates.CalculateDaysTest2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Calculate Dates Test 2</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"
            ItemType="PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Models.Lease"
            DataKeyNames="LeaseID" 
            RenderOuterTable="false" 
            DefaultMode="Insert"
            InsertMethod="LeaseFormAdd_InsertItem">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="formitem">
                        <asp:Label ID="startDateLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="Start Date:"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="DatePicker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="calculateDays" Text="<%#: BindItem.StartDate %>"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formitem">
                        <asp:Label ID="endDateLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="End Date:"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID ="txtEndDate"  CssClass="DatePicker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="calculateDays" Text="<%#: BindItem.EndDate %>"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formitem">
                        <asp:Label ID="totalDaysLabel" CssClass="formlabel" runat="server" Text="Number of Days:"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="totalDays" CssClass="idlabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" Text="Insert" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" CommandName="Insert" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" CommandName="Cancel"/> 
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.DatePicker').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '1950:2100'
            });
        })
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CalculateDaysTest2.cs

```
using System;
using PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Models;

namespace PopeyeMarinaWebApp.Templates
{
public partial class CalculateDaysTest2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void LeaseFormAdd_InsertItem()
    {
        var item = new Lease();
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (MarinaDBContext db = new MarinaDBContext())
            {
                db.Leases.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void calculateDays(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string startdate = txtStartDate.Text;
        string enddate = txtEndDate.Text;
        if (startdate != "" && enddate != "")
        {
            DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
            DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);
            totalDays.Text = t2.Subtract(t1).Days.ToString();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I'm getting an error in the calculateDays event which says:
'The name 'textStartDate' does not exist in the current context'
'The name 'textEndDate' does not exist in the current context'
'The name 'totalDays' does not exist in the current context'

I'm just wondering why this doesn't work within a Form View control and how can I fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0):

You've placed your code inside an "asp:FormView", which is preventing you from accessing your TextBox's etc directly in the code behind.

You'll need to setup something to handle commands from your FormView. In the code behind, you'll need something like this - although the example below is written off the top of my head.

```
void FormView1_ItemCommand(Object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtStartDate = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtStartDate");
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Note you need to connect this code using the "OnItemCommand" property of your FormView on the aspx page.

See the MSDN documentation for a more extensive example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

As for accessing the TextBox's anywhere in the code behind, you'll need to use the FindControl method on the FormView. Something like one of these:

```
TextBox txtStartDate = (TextBox)FormView1.Row.FindControl("txtStartDate");
```

Or

```
TextBox txtStartDate = (TextBox)FormView1.InsertItem.FindControl("txtStartDate");
```

Comment: I typed that code in and now it's giving me an error: 'FormViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extenion method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'FormViewCommandEventArgs' could be found.

Comment: When I tried the 2nd code, it does work for me and I'm able to access the text boxes in the Form View. Thanks.